# Wordpress cache login issue (w3 total cache)

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

I am using w3 total cache, and only few of its functions are on - browser cache, page cache. Yet when someone tries to login, seems like they have the homepage or other pages cached because they have visited them few minutes ago, and if after loging in they try to visit the same pages they appear logged out, unles the refresh the page.

The loging itself works, but it's not visible for the browser until refresh. Do you have any suggestions to which cache might be connected. Because I use the cache to speed up the website and so I need it, but if users keep complaining, I might need to turn it off since I don't want to lose the visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Dashboard (Performance > General Settings) there's a *Debug* section where you can turn on debugging for all the different caches, and it adds comments to the HTML source code, so you can see which pages / objects / DB queries have been cached.

If you enable debugging for *Page Cache*, if it can't cache the page it'll say `Caching: disabled` and give you a reason, e.g. `User is logged in` (by default, pages for logged in users aren't cached.)

Remember to turn debugging off again when you've finished.

Note questions about third-party plugins are off-topic here; the best place to seek support would be the [W3 Total Cache plugin page](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/w3-total-cache).

Comment: Well it doesn't have one for browser cache. I will post on the specific plugin support forum, just wanted to know your opinion too, if anyone encountered such login non login.

Comment: The items in browser cache are all things you can verify with your browser's developer tools (e.g. the various cache/expiry headers that are sent, whether the page is gzipped etc.) - [Relevant bit of Chrome DevTools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#http-headers)